# How to replace a specific word in a specific line of text

Tags: java, file-io

Okay, so I have this yaml file, and I want to replace a string

```
socialspy: true
```

with the string

```
socialspy: false
```

But I don't know how to. Here is the full yaml document

```
timestamps:
  login: 1395784099618
  lastteleport: 1395785353975
  logout: 1395777644566
  mute: 0
ipAddress: 127.0.0.1
lastlocation:
  world: world
  x: -276.7695097103249
  y: 67.31022115326866
  z: -354.327229975015
  yaw: 127.892334
  pitch: 20.817677
money: '155200.0'
logoutlocation:
  world: world
  x: -252.00777100946556
  y: 76.56983022033046
  z: -348.45387330548886
  yaw: 319.99237
  pitch: 19.562881
socialspy: true
godmode: true
afk: false
powertools:
muted: false
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you know how to read the file, do you need that info too?

Comment: I know how to read the file, but I don't have a clue of how to read for a specific line, and replace it with new text.

Comment: Read the file, then write it back, replacing the line of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a decent OS and that your YAML document is called `doc`:

```
sed -i 's/socialspy: true/socialspy: false/' doc
```

Answer (score 0):

ِYou need some thing similar to :

```
String string = "timestamps: login ...";
string = string.replace("socialspy: true", "socialspy: false");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the line from the file, try checking if the string contains "socialspy" you can use the String.contains() methods

If the line contains your string, then you can user [String.replaceFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or  String.replace()

But it does look like you are using a JSON style string, try looking more into JSON.