# How to find a specific line in a text file, and replace it with something else

Tags: java, replace

Ok, So I am trying to search through a yaml file to find a specific line of code

The yaml file will normally look like this, but it could have plus or minus a few other lines:

```
timestamps:
  login: 1397256621980
  logout: 1397267743528
  lastteleport: 1397265370690
ipAddress: 127.0.0.1
lastlocation:
  world: world
  x: -208.52097206207856
  y: 64.0
  z: -367.26689797238714
  yaw: 199.81995
  pitch: 11.099998
logoutlocation:
  world: world
  x: -160.36469909073216
  y: 64.0
  z: -422.31472024960175
  yaw: 235.05505
  pitch: 30.90003
money: '1.0'
socialspy: true
afk: false
uuid: b735fgb3-9830-3556-bdf3-5abdd9206368
powertools: {}
```

I am trying to replace the line

```
socialspy: true
```

with

```
socialspy: false
```

but after about 30 minutes I've had no luck. I know basic knowledge of scanners, but nothing about file writers and such.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you should do some research on file writers and such.

Comment: Do NOT edit the file in place. Write the result to another file and only then rename to the original

Comment: Is it a bad thing to edit the file in place?

Comment: How is this question different from [your last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647716/how-to-replace-a-specific-word-in-a-specific-line-of-text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file line by line and check if it's not the `bad string` write it to a new file:

```
try {
String oldFile = "oldFileNname";
String newFile = "newFileName";
PrintWriter f = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFile));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    if (line.equals("socialspy: true")) {
        f.println("socialspy: false");
    }
    else {
        f.println(line);
    }
}
br.close();
f.close();
}catch (IOException e) {
    //OMG Exception again!
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I'm still having problems with actually replacing the line. That's the part that I'm stuck on.

Comment: You're welcome, I just added that part.

Comment: Thanks it works. I had to change one thing with the code you gave me though... You closed the PrintWriter too soon!

Comment: @user3461895> haha, yes, I'll edit it.